# How to retrieve messages from non-owned discord server

Tags: python, api, discord, text-mining

I'm writing a code for text analysis and Matlab and want to get messages from a discord server that I don't own according to a search query. First question? is that possible?

Second: are there any good tutorials on how to do that in Python? (discord.py client.run() gives me a asyncio error even after installing nest_async)

Thanks a lot,
Omar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it would be via Discord Web and Selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

Set up selenium to go to Discord Web, Log in and type the query in the search field. Use BeautifulSoup to parse it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I voted up actually.  Is there a guide or something on how to automate this process? because I'd like to automate different queries, servers, and dates.

Comment: I don't think i am aware of a guide. But if you post any more questions to stackoverflow and tag me, I'll be happy to answer them all!